# GRUB2 menu in early config

Tags: grub2

I'm trying to create a menu in the early config file of GRUB 2.04 in file `early.cfg`:

```
menuentry foo {
  echo foo1
}
menuentry bar {
  echo bar1
}
```

I'm building core.img with:

```
$ grub-mkimage -v -v -v -C xz -O i386-pc -p /prefix -o core.img -c early.cfg biosdisk part_msdos part_gpt luks linux16 gcry_rijndael gcry_sha512 gcry_sha256 lvm chain cpio gzio xzio search echo fat ext2 reiserfs btrfs zfs xfs ntfs ntfscomp
```

At boot time no filesystems are available (yet) to load grub.cfg from. When I boot, I get the `grub>` prompt.

How do I get to the menu? I tried typing `normal` + *Enter*, *Esc*, *Esc*, but it doesn't show me the menu, it just puts me back to the `grub>` prompt with the screen cleared.

Ultimately I'd like to activate the menu defined in the early config by default. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the GRUB2 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Embedded-configuration), it's impossible to have menu entries in `early.cfg`:

> The embedded configuration file may not contain menu entries directly, but may only read them from elsewhere using `configfile`.